# Is There An XSL Code Generator That Can Create XSLT By Example?

Tags: xml, xslt, editor, generator

Given a source XML document and a sample of what it should look like after it is transformed, is there a code generator that could create an XSL transform to accomplish that.

I am not expecting it to be perfect but, much like the code generators that can create XSD from sample XML, it would be a good starting point to then refine by hand.

Comment: See the similar question [How to generate XSLT from XML samples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482759/how-to-generate-xslt-from-xml-samples) for possible solutions.

Comment: That being said, XSLT isn't really that hard to write, especially in VS 2010. It doesn't have much of a "vocabulary", LOL. Admittedly it can get laborious though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[XSLTGen](http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/baileyj/xsltgen/XSLTGen.htm) looks promising and exactly what you're looking for.

---

*Update: (4-Apr-2015)*
*Updated the link to the correct link as pointed to by: @user326608*

Answer (score 7):

What you're asking is, essentially, "Given a set of input data and an output, is it possible to infer the logic of a program that will produce that output?"  Except for the trivial case - where the program produces the provided output irrespective of the input - the answer is "No."

Comment: +1 For the word "trivial". Indeed, if the output HTML contains `<td>4</td>`, it may be due to dumping the result of `2*2`, `count(mynodes)` or the value of `/homer_simpson/@number_of_fingers`.

Comment: That it isn't possible to do something in general doesn't mean it isn't possible in some/most practical cases.

Comment: That's why there are two branches of computer science and physics, applied and theoretical.  You good provide such a program hints by tagging where the data goes, but if you do enough of it, you start to question the utility of the said program rather than go directly to xslt.

Answer (score 1):

try ALTOVA MapForce (http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html)

Comment: Is this available on Ubuntu 20 without going through virtual box ?