# Free XML converter to convert XML to HTML / CSV file formats

Tags: xml

Is there any Free software, XML converter to convert XML to HTML / CSV file format.

Comment: You might need to provide a bit more clarity on your question. If converting to HTML do you want a HTML rendering of the actual XML file, or do you want the HTML file to be a presentation view of the information content of the XML file. As for the CSV that would depend on the structure of your XML. XML is very hierarchical and CSV is not.

Comment: Ok... To convert XML file to render as data in terms of HTML representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At codeplex there is an open source project tailored to do conversion from XML to CSV. It does not do XML to HTML. You find the code and executable software [here](http://xmltocsv.codeplex.com).

Comment: The URL down.  Website codeplex.com has been shutdown. Refer to:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/shutting-down-codeplex/

Comment: I moved it: https://github.com/timmytimeless/xmltocsv

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally you would use xslt to represent xml has html.

Toutorial on XSLT: 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp

Here is a similar question to the one you asked which offers an opensource software to generate xslt automatically: [Is There An XSL Code Generator That Can Create XSLT By Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483064/402706)

Comment: The W3schools link is done